# Can't find a precompilied version of PyCrypto 2.6 for windows x64

Tags: python-2.7, pycrypto

Does anyone know where I could find a precompilied version of pycrypto 2.6.1 for Windows x64?
I found http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto but I can't download the file. The link is broken.

Of course, there is the option of building the library from scratch but I don't want to do that.

Comment: What is the error. What is in your site-packages folder?

Comment: The error is exactly the same as the one described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787258/pycrypto-install-error-on-windows.
There are 3 solutions basically: 
Install VS2008 and build the library.
Install MinGW and build the library from thereDownload a precompilied. 2.6.1 pycrypto library from somewhere in the Internet.

Comment: I prefer going with the 3rd solution since it possibly the easiest one. If not I'll just install and compile pycrypto with MinGW.

Comment: The links on that page work for me

Comment: lol. The link - Crypto 2.6 for Python 2.7 64bit - works now. Anyway, thanks for update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The download link PyCrypto 2.6 works for Python 2.7 64bit in 
http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto works.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20190324172744/www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml if down