# PyCrypto for Python 3.4 on Windows 8.1 cannot find winrandom module

Tags: python-3.x, paramiko, pycrypto

I've been trying to install Paramiko in a Python 3.4 virtual environment. I tried `pip` installing, as well as `easy_installing` with pre-built binaries and neither worked. [Suggested Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787258/pycrypto-install-error-on-windows) Both kept saying that `winrandom is not a valid Win32 application.`

I found that is is a problem with PyCrypto, and not Paramiko directly, so I installed from source and pre-built binaries and still can't get it to find/use a module called `winrandom.`

Have any of you solved this problem? It's very frustrating.

Comment: 2.6.1 has a [relative import](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/commit/10abfc8633bac653eda4d346fc051b2f07554dcd#diff-f14623ba167ec6ff27cbf0e005d732a7) that's fixed in 2.7. Probably all you need to do is fix that import in `Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py`.

Comment: @eryksun thanks for finding that for me, I'll have to try it tomorrow. I was so frustrated I started back porting from 3.4 to 2.7

Comment: yep, that's fixed it. @eryksun - maybe you should post it as an answer. So the question will can be closed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.6.1 has a [relative import](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/commit/10abfc8633bac653eda4d346fc051b2f07554dcd#diff-f14623ba167ec6ff27cbf0e005d732a7) that's fixed in 2.7. Probably all you need to do is fix that import in `Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py`

Comment: How did you rectify the above error? I am trying to install paramiko but getting error no module name winrandom. I searched but couldn't find winrandom for python 3.4

Comment: Updated my answer with a link to the fix.

Answer (score 4):

From the same link, change nt.py (...\Lib\site-packages\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py)

change

```
import winrandom
```

to

```
from . import winrandom
```

Answer (score 3):

Not really sure if this is helpfull for you guys, but i got the problem that I was not able to install winrandom for python3.4

With the foolowing link, I fixed my problem
https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/commit/10abfc8633bac653eda4d346fc051b2f07554dcd